# Remove :focus outline style from ::before and ::after pseudo elements

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Using a Bootstrap switch, I want to remove the blue outline on the toggle when focused. Typically I would just apply `#element:focus { outline: none; }` but because they are rendered using pseudo-elements, I'm not able to do this.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3adqw24v/)

```
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">
        <span>Show Favorites</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need your CSS selector to be more specific or match what Boostrap is doing in this case it's actually a box-shadow not outline:

```
.custom-control-input:focus~.custom-control-label::before {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Sample: https://jsfiddle.net/q2rjxzob/1/

Here's a trick the focus is always on the `input` itself that's what keeps it accessible. Use your development tool to activate the `:focus` and see where the styles are being applied. Select the `:before` element to see:

[image]

Comment: Ah, thanks!. I kept trying to force the focused state on the `::before`! Thank for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

```
.custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::before {
    box-shadow: none;
}

.custom-control-input:empty~.custom-control-label::before {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```